# EXCEL VBA EVENT ARRAY

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, events

I want the vba event array & dictionary code because there are 50 thousand row records. the code I made sometimes runs and sometimes it doesn't run maybe something is wrong in my code.If I use the formula it will run very slowly.

I tried to copy 2 lines in the code column but the results of my vba code do not match and can only run if I do only copy 1 line in the code column and I also use it as a form in the receive item sheet, can it work if the formula becomes vba in the MASTER RI (ROLL) sheet?

for information I use excel 2010
Formula information in sheet ("MASTER RI (ROLL)")

```
Column A :=IF(I2='RECEIVE ITEM'!$F$7,N(A1)+1,N(A1))
Column B :=IF(MAX($C$2:$C$57675)<ROW(1:1),"",VLOOKUP(ROW(1:1),$C$2:$I$57675,7,0))
Column C : =IF(COUNTIF(I$1:I2,I2)=1,MAX(C$1:C1)+1,"")
Column D : =IF([@[SUPPLIER NAME]]="","",VLOOKUP([@[SUPPLIER NAME]],Table2[[#All],[SUPPLIER NAME]:[POSTAL CODE]],3,0))
Column E : =IF([@[SUPPLIER NAME]]="","",VLOOKUP([@[SUPPLIER NAME]],Table2[[#All],[SUPPLIER NAME]:[POSTAL CODE]],4,0))
Column F :=IF([@[SUPPLIER NAME]]="","",VLOOKUP([@[SUPPLIER NAME]],Table2[[#All],[SUPPLIER NAME]:[POSTAL CODE]],6,0))
Column G :=IF([@[QTY IN ACTUAL]]=""," ",[@[QTY IN ACTUAL]])
Column Q : =[@[QTY IN ACTUAL]]*[@rate]
Column T : =[@[QTY IN ACTUAL]]*[@[NEW PRICE]]
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
 Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Intersect(Target, Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim fnd As Range
    Set fnd = Sheets("MASTER").Range("B:B").Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then

Target.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 3))
Target.Offset(, 4).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 6))
Target.Offset(, 6).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 8))
Target.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 4))

    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**MASTER RI (ROLL)**
[image: MASTER RI (ROLL)]

**DB SUPPLIER**
[image: DB SUPPLIER]

**RECEIVE ITEM**
[image: RECEIVE ITEM]

**MASTER**
[image: MASTER]

Comment: @braX , 
ok I have updated the file link

Comment: @braX , 
I updated on the hyperlink